# The tab is locked and cannot be updated

Tags: docusignapi

I'm making a request to update the value of a text field in an envelope. Here is the request I make. `PUT /accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients/{recipientId}/tabs`

With the body

```
{
     "textTabs": [
        {
            "value": "MY NEW VALUE",
            "tabId": "{tabId}"
        }
    ]
}
```

The envelope I'm updating is a draft envelope (status of created), and the recipient is the recipient I get the tabs of to find the tabId. However the response I get back is this.

```
{
  "textTabs": [
    {
      "height": 11,
      "requireAll": "false",
      "width": 42,
      "concealValueOnDocument": "false",
      "disableAutoSize": "false",
      "recipientId": "{recipientId}",
      "tabId": "{tabId}",
      "errorDetails": {
        "errorCode": "INVALID_TAB_OPERATION",
        "message": "The Tab specified is not valid for the requested operation.  The tab is locked and cannot be updated."
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

However, if I get an editing console for the draft envelope, I'm able to update the field fine. It's the same field in both instance (only field where the tabLabel and name in the REST response matches the data label and tooltip of the request).

Even if the provider of the template locked the template (which I believe to be true, I cannot get an edit console on the template: "This user is not authorized to access the requested template. User does not have rights to edit shared templates."), I should still be able to update the tab on a draft envelope, correct?  What do I need to do to edit this tab?

**UPDATE:**

We have noticed that the "templateLocked" field is true on any tabs we cannot change. However, as noted they can be changed in the views/edit console. Why can we change them there and not here? Is there any way to change them here?

Comment: "they can be changed in the views/edit console" .... That should not be possible. If a tab is locked in the template, any envelope created from the template will inherit the setting. It should not be possible to edit the locked tab either through api or the web console. Are you sure you are editing the envelope created from the correct template?

Comment: Can you please provide the envelopeId that you are editing in the console. I am interested in seeing whether it is an envelope or a template.

Answer (score 0):

The template might have set the **Restrict Changes** flag for the Tab. Any envelope created from the template will inherit the setting.

See [sender permission settings for a field](https://www.docusign.com/DocuSignHelp/Content/locked-templates.htm)

When the Restrict Changes flag is set "sender cannot change any field properties or delete the field"